# to find and eliminate logical duplicates

Tags: sql

```
A|B|100
B|A|100
D|A|100
```

from above data 3 records 2 are logical duplicates . need a query to get one record from logical duplicates

Comment: Specify the expected result as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with conditional grouping:

```
select 
  case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end col1, 
  case when col1 < col2 then col2 else col1 end col2, 
  col3
from tablename
group by 
  case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end,
  case when col1 < col2 then col2 else col1 end,
  col3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mzgDxV1QCK1jAN2a1NKQXb/0).
Results:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| ---- | ---- | ---- |
| A    | B    | 100  |
| A    | D    | 100  |
```

Comment: F_name , L_name, sal
       
        Shiva   , Reddy ,1000
     Reddy  ,  Shiva  , 1000

Comment: see i have data like that . with f_name ,L_name and sal . first two records are logical duplicates.

Comment: So change col1, col2, col3 to F_name , L_name, sal respectively.

Comment: its working . i got the expected output only. thank you so  much  .

Comment: Sure .. you dont mind can you explain  how it will work?

Comment: The 1st case statement returns the min of the 2 values and the 2nd the max of the 2 values. So A, B becomes A, B (it is the same) and B, A become A, B. Then when you group by them, grouping eliminates duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no other duplicates, I recommend:

```
select t.*
from t
where col1 < col2
union all
select t.*
from t
where col1 > col2 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.col1 = t.col2 and
                        t2.col2 = t.col1 and
                        t2.col3 = t.col3
                 );
```

This method will keep the original rows in the data.  You can also express it using `or` instead of `union all`:

```
select t.*
from t
where (col1 < col2) or
      (col1 > col2 and
       not exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where t2.col1 = t.col2 and
                         t2.col2 = t.col1 and
                         t2.col3 = t.col3
                  )
      );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3561babad9122f2a4e7a547e4c090831) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: where we declared  t1 ?

Comment: thanks for the query  but its displaying the only one record . its not displaying 3rd record.

Comment: @ShivaReddySingam . . . Of course it works.  I added a db<>fiddle to illustrate it working.